# Different types of paragraphs, how to simplify? Is a single environment possible?

Tags: environments, memoir, paragraphs

I want **to simplify the way of writing content** that will have two types of paragraphs:

1. For the **narrative part**, a hanging paragraph style and the first line without a left margin.
2. For the **interlocutor part**, a paragraph with greater left and right indentation and without indentation.

With my little knowledge of LaTex I have managed to advance a bit, but I have two difficulties:

*a*. I have used two different environments to solve (1) and (2), but **writing the text is not simple** because this way constantly forces me to be opening and closing environments. Is there a simpler way to do it, for example defining a command for (2) and making all content within a block spanning environment?

*b*. In the environment `readtalk` it only works for me when there is a single paragraph. I need this to work with **multiple paragraphs** as well.

### Code

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
% -------------------------------------------------------Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{csquotes} 


    
\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}
    
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Noto Serif}        

\newenvironment{readbody}{\everypar{\hangafter=1 \notoserif \small \leftskip-0.5cm\relax \setlength{\hangindent}{4em}}}{\par}

\newenvironment{readtalk}{%
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    %\addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \notoserif
    \small
    \ignorespaces
    \leftskip0.8cm\relax
    \rightskip0.8cm\relax
    \noindent   
}
{% \end{cr}
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    %\addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space below
    %\noindent
}


\begin{document}

    \mainmatter

\begin{readbody}
    Antes de la fiesta de la Pascua, sabiendo Jesús que había llegado su hora de pasar de este mundo al Padre, habiendo amado a los suyos que estaban en el mundo, los amó hasta el extremo. 
    
    Estaban cenando; ya el diablo había suscitado en el corazón de Judas, hijo de Simón Iscariote, la intención de entregarlo; y Jesús, sabiendo que el Padre había puesto todo en sus manos, que venía de Dios y a Dios volvía, se levanta de la cena, se quita el manto y, tomando una toalla, se la ciñe; luego echa agua en la jofaina y se pone a lavarles los pies a los discípulos, secándoselos con la toalla que se había ceñido. 
    
    Llegó a Simón Pedro y este le dice: 
\end{readbody}  

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{Señor, ¿lavarme los pies tú a mí?}.
\end{readtalk}  

\begin{readbody}
    Jesús le replicó: 
\end{readbody}

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{Lo que yo hago, tú no lo entiendes ahora, pero lo comprenderás más tarde}.
    
    Another paragraph ... It's not working ....
\end{readtalk}  

\begin{readbody}
    Pedro le dice: 
\end{readbody}

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{No me lavarás los pies jamás}.
\end{readtalk}  

\begin{readbody}
    Jesús le contestó: 
\end{readbody}

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{Si no te lavo, no tienes parte conmigo}. 
\end{readtalk}  

\begin{readbody}
    Simón Pedro le dice: 
\end{readbody}

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{Señor, no solo los pies, sino también las manos y la cabeza}.
\end{readtalk}  

\begin{readbody}
    Jesús le dice: 
\end{readbody}

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{Uno que se ha bañado no necesita lavarse más que los pies, porque todo él está limpio. También vosotros estáis limpios, aunque no todos}. 
\end{readtalk}  

\begin{readbody}
    Porque sabía quién lo iba a entregar, por eso dijo: \textquote{No todos estáis limpios}. 
    
    Cuando acabó de lavarles los pies, tomó el manto, se lo puso otra vez y les dijo: 
\end{readbody}

\begin{readtalk}    
    \textquote{¿Comprendéis lo que he hecho con vosotros? Vosotros me llamáis \textquote{el Maestro} y \textquote{el Señor}, y decís bien, porque lo soy. Pues si yo, el Maestro y el Señor, os he lavado los pies, también vosotros debéis lavaros los pies unos a otros: os he dado ejemplo para que lo que yo he hecho con vosotros, vosotros también lo hagáis}.
\end{readtalk}
    
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: In the `readtalk` environment, the issue is paragraph indenting.  Therefore, replace `\noindent` with `\parindent 0pt`

Comment: You could also replace the `readtalk` environment with a macro `\newcommand\xreadtalk[1]{\begingroup
    \par
    \notoserif
    \small
    \ignorespaces
    \leftskip0.8cm\relax
    \rightskip0.8cm\relax
    \parindent 0pt\relax
    #1\par\endgroup}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of markup:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Noto Serif}

\newenvironment{scripture}
 {%
  \par
  \notoserif\small
  \parindent=0pt
  \everypar{\hangindent0.8cm\hangafter=1}%
  \let\>\talk
 }
 {\par}
\newcommand{\talk}{\par\hspace*{0.8cm}\ignorespaces}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\begin{scripture}
Antes de la fiesta de la Pascua, sabiendo Jesús que había llegado su 
hora de pasar de este mundo al Padre, habiendo amado a los suyos que 
estaban en el mundo, los amó hasta el extremo. 

Estaban cenando; ya el diablo había suscitado en el corazón de Judas, 
hijo de Simón Iscariote, la intención de entregarlo; y Jesús, sabiendo 
que el Padre había puesto todo en sus manos, que venía de Dios y a Dios 
volvía, se levanta de la cena, se quita el manto y, tomando una toalla, 
se la ciñe; luego echa agua en la jofaina y se pone a lavarles los pies 
a los discípulos, secándoselos con la toalla que se había ceñido. 

Llegó a Simón Pedro y este le dice: 

\> \textquote{Señor, ¿lavarme los pies tú a mí?}

Jesús le replicó: 

\> \textquote{Lo que yo hago, tú no lo entiendes ahora, pero lo comprenderás más tarde}

\> Another paragraph ... It's not working ....

Pedro le dice: 

\> \textquote{No me lavarás los pies jamás}.

Jesús le contestó: 

\> \textquote{Si no te lavo, no tienes parte conmigo}. 

Simón Pedro le dice: 

\> \textquote{Señor, no solo los pies, sino también las manos y la cabeza}.

Jesús le dice: 

\> \textquote{Uno que se ha bañado no necesita lavarse más que los pies, porque 
todo él está limpio. También vosotros estáis limpios, aunque no todos}. 

Porque sabía quién lo iba a entregar, por eso dijo: \textquote{No todos 
estáis limpios}. 

Cuando acabó de lavarles los pies, tomó el manto, se lo puso otra vez y 
les dijo: 

\> \textquote{¿Comprendéis lo que he hecho con vosotros? Vosotros me llamáis 
\textquote{el Maestro} y \textquote{el Señor}, y decís bien, porque lo soy. 
Pues si yo, el Maestro y el Señor, os he lavado los pies, también vosotros 
debéis lavaros los pies unos a otros: os he dado ejemplo para que lo que 
yo he hecho con vosotros, vosotros también lo hagáis}.
\end{scripture}

\end{document}
```

In order to avoid `\textquote` one might define `\talk` with an argument

```
\newcommand{\talk}[1]{\par\hspace*{0.8cm}\textquote{#1}}
```

and call

```
\>{Si no te lavo, no tienes parte conmigo}.
```

[image]

If your indented lines (on both sides) contains spoken text in quotes (how much I dislike the period after the closing quote), you can do like this:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Noto Serif}

\newenvironment{scripture}
 {%
  \par
  \notoserif\small
  \parindent=0pt
  \everypar{\hangindent0.8cm\hangafter=1}%
  \let\>\talk
 }
 {\par}
\newcommand{\talk}[2]{%
  \par
  {% start a group
   \rightskip=0.8cm
   \hspace*{0.8cm}%
   \textquote{#1}%
   \ifx.#2.\par\else#2\fi
  }% end the group
}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\begin{scripture}
Antes de la fiesta de la Pascua, sabiendo Jesús que había llegado su 
hora de pasar de este mundo al Padre, habiendo amado a los suyos que 
estaban en el mundo, los amó hasta el extremo. 

Estaban cenando; ya el diablo había suscitado en el corazón de Judas, 
hijo de Simón Iscariote, la intención de entregarlo; y Jesús, sabiendo 
que el Padre había puesto todo en sus manos, que venía de Dios y a Dios 
volvía, se levanta de la cena, se quita el manto y, tomando una toalla, 
se la ciñe; luego echa agua en la jofaina y se pone a lavarles los pies 
a los discípulos, secándoselos con la toalla que se había ceñido. 

Llegó a Simón Pedro y este le dice: 

\>{Señor, ¿lavarme los pies tú a mí?}

Jesús le replicó: 

\>{Lo que yo hago, tú no lo entiendes ahora, pero lo comprenderás más tarde}.

\>{Another paragraph}.

Pedro le dice: 

\>{No me lavarás los pies jamás}.

Jesús le contestó: 

\>{Si no te lavo, no tienes parte conmigo}. 

Simón Pedro le dice: 

\>{Señor, no solo los pies, sino también las manos y la cabeza}.

Jesús le dice: 

\>{Uno que se ha bañado no necesita lavarse más que los pies, porque 
todo él está limpio. También vosotros estáis limpios, aunque no todos}. 

Porque sabía quién lo iba a entregar, por eso dijo: \textquote{No todos 
estáis limpios}. 

Cuando acabó de lavarles los pies, tomó el manto, se lo puso otra vez y 
les dijo: 

\>{¿Comprendéis lo que he hecho con vosotros? Vosotros me llamáis 
\textquote{el Maestro} y \textquote{el Señor}, y decís bien, porque lo soy. 
Pues si yo, el Maestro y el Señor, os he lavado los pies, también vosotros 
debéis lavaros los pies unos a otros: os he dado ejemplo para que lo que 
yo he hecho con vosotros, vosotros también lo hagáis}.
\end{scripture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. How I can set more right margin for `\talk`? In the original code I had `\rightskip0.8cm\relax`. With your code that space is not there, it is the only thing missing for it to work as expected.

Comment: @A.Cedano I added a possible solution. Do you *really* need the period after the closing quote?

Comment: Yes, I need the period after the closing quote. It comes like this in the original text and I would not like to change it. It's working as expected with the new code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my two earlier comments:

1. setting `\parindent 0pt` in `readtalk`
2. replace `readtalk` environment with `\xreadtalk` macro

I have also implemented a 3rd change

3. Make `|` active as delimiters to indicate `\xreadtalk`.  Thus `|blah blah|` sets `blah blah` in the `\xreadtalk` style.

As I have set it up, `|...|` can only be effectively used inside the `readbody` environment, as it closes out the extant `readbody` environment, does its thing, and then reopens it.

Thus, only a single `readbody` environment is needed for the complete passage, and inside that environment, multiple delimited `|...|` "readtalks" can occur.

Here is the MWE

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
% -------------------------------------------------------Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{csquotes} 


    
\setmainfont{Arial-Bold}%{Libertinus Sans}
    
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Arial}%{Noto Serif}        

\newenvironment{readbody}{\everypar{\hangafter=1 \notoserif \small \leftskip-0.5cm\relax \setlength{\hangindent}{4em}}}{\par}

\newcommand\xreadtalk[1]{\begingroup
    \par
    \notoserif
    \small
    \ignorespaces
    \leftskip0.8cm\relax
    \rightskip0.8cm\relax
    \parindent 0pt\relax
    #1\par\endgroup}   

\catcode`|=\active
\long\def|#1|{\end{readbody}\xreadtalk{#1}\begin{readbody}}

\begin{document}

    \mainmatter

\begin{readbody}
    Antes de la fiesta de la Pascua, sabiendo Jesús que había llegado su hora de pasar de este mundo al Padre, habiendo amado a los suyos que estaban en el mundo, los amó hasta el extremo. 
    
    Estaban cenando; ya el diablo había suscitado en el corazón de Judas, hijo de Simón Iscariote, la intención de entregarlo; y Jesús, sabiendo que el Padre había puesto todo en sus manos, que venía de Dios y a Dios volvía, se levanta de la cena, se quita el manto y, tomando una toalla, se la ciñe; luego echa agua en la jofaina y se pone a lavarles los pies a los discípulos, secándoselos con la toalla que se había ceñido. 
    
    Llegó a Simón Pedro y este le dice: 

|\textquote{Señor, ¿lavarme los pies tú a mí?}.|

    Jesús le replicó: 

|\textquote{Lo que yo hago, tú no lo entiendes ahora, pero lo comprenderás más tarde}.
    
    Another paragraph ... It's not working ....
 fgkdfgldf kldfgkj fdklj dfjgklkjfd fdgklkfdg kdflkfdg lkfdg klfdg|

    Pedro le dice: 

|\textquote{No me lavarás los pies jamás}.|  

    Jesús le contestó: 

|\textquote{Si no te lavo, no tienes parte conmigo}.|  

    Simón Pedro le dice: 

|\textquote{Señor, no solo los pies, sino también las manos y la cabeza}.|  

    Jesús le dice: 

|\textquote{Uno que se ha bañado no necesita lavarse más que los pies, porque todo él está limpio. También vosotros estáis limpios, aunque no todos}.|  

    Porque sabía quién lo iba a entregar, por eso dijo: \textquote{No todos estáis limpios}. 
    
    Cuando acabó de lavarles los pies, tomó el manto, se lo puso otra vez y les dijo: 

|\textquote{¿Comprendéis lo que he hecho con vosotros? Vosotros me llamáis \textquote{el Maestro} y \textquote{el Señor}, y decís bien, porque lo soy. Pues si yo, el Maestro y el Señor, os he lavado los pies, también vosotros debéis lavaros los pies unos a otros: os he dado ejemplo para que lo que yo he hecho con vosotros, vosotros también lo hagáis}.|

\end{readbody}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]